# My point annotation in Chart.js 3.3.2 won't render in my Django template. Making a realtime graph of temperature for my wood-fired pizza oven

Tags: python, django, chart.js

**The goal and problem:**
I'm having trouble getting an annotation to render in Chart.js. My project is a Django/Chart.js-run graph that shows the temperature of my wood fire pizza oven. I would like to see the temperature graphed over time and be able to submit a model form indicating when I have shut the door, and to have that annotated on the graph.

**Specific issue**
The issue is that I can't get the annotation to render on my graph, partly because I am unsure what x/y coordinate to put in. This can be seen in the const options variable in my index.html. In order, have attached my  base.html, index.html, view.py, and forms.py. I also included a link to a screen shot of the graph so far and of my pizza oven in case you're curious. :P

**Versions**
I'm using Python 3.9.5, Chartjs 3.3.2, and Django 3.2.4.

Would be grateful for some help!
-Mike

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Chartjs CDN-->
    <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>-->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>


    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

</head>

<body>

   

      {% block content %}

      {% endblock content %}

  

<!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->

</body>


</html>
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<body>

<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

<!--This chart will graph temperature of my oven. I would like to be able to annotate
the graph to show when I have closed my oven door. This annotation will be handled by a form, which 
will store data inthe sqlite database. I would like to display an annotation on the graph but
I can't seem to get it working-->

<script>
    const options = {
        plugins: {
            autocolors: false,
            annotation: {
                annotations: {
                    point1: {
                        type: 'point',
                        xValue: '{{ q_recent.dateposted }}', //I don't know what to put here to get the annotation
                        yValue: '{{ q_recent.dateposted }}', //I don't know what to put here to get the annotation
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.25)'
                    }
                }
            }
        }          
    };

    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            /* the labels and data are created in the view variable "q_recent" and then using the for loop
            the labels and data are plugged in to the labels and data below*/

            labels: [{% for q_recent in q_recent %} '{{ q_recent.dateposted }}', {% endfor %}],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Pizza Oven Temp',
                data: [{% for q_recent in q_recent %} '{{ q_recent.oventemperature }}', {% endfor %}],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                tension: 0.3
            }]
        },
        options
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'),config);

</script>

<!--reference to the model form below (called form, see forms.py) allows me to submit a true value 
for the boolean variable "isdoorclosed'" to the database, marking when I have closed my oven door-->
<br>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="border p-3 shadow">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                <input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Enter">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

{% endblock content %}
```

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
import random
import time
from .forms import OvenDataForm
from .models import OvenData

def index(request):
    #The next  oven temperature data and store it in the database.
    for i in range(1,15):
        temp_random = random.randint(400,1000)
        ambient_random = random.randint(13,20)
        #the below two lines puts values in the database and sets the object to q for further refernece in the context
        q = OvenData.objects.create(oventemperature=temp_random, ambienttemperature = ambient_random, dateposted = timezone.now(), timecloseddoor = timezone.now(), isdoorclosed = False)
        q.save()
    
    #this gives me the last 10 database values to be printed in the graph.
    q_recent = OvenData.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]

    #this will confirm that the latest value I am getting from the database is properly printed to the template
    print(ambient_random)
    print(temp_random)
    
    """the model variables below:
    oventemperature = models.FloatField(null = True)
    ambienttemperature = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True)
    dateposted = models.TimeField(null = True)
    timecloseddoor = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    isdoorclosed = models.BooleanField(blank = True, default=False) """
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OvenDataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # here I'm saying, don' save it yet, I want to change something about the data. 
            # In my case I'm putting other values along with the door closed variable coming from the form.
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.oventemperature = 799.9
            obj.ambienttemperature = ambient_random
            obj.dateposted = timezone.now()
            obj.timecloseddoor = timezone.now()
            print(q.isdoorclosed)
            obj.save()
            
            #I took out this redirect to the home page because it was loading the page again. I stopped
            # this given this cues up the index view which causes random data to be generated and saved.
            
            #return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = OvenDataForm()
    
    context = {
        'q_recent': q_recent,
        'q': q,
        'form': form
        }
    
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

```html
from django import forms

from .models import OvenData

""" 
oventemperature = models.FloatField(null = True)
    ambienttemperature = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True)
    dateposted = models.TimeField(null = True)
    timecloseddoor = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    #using blank=false means that the field is required. Null=True means it can be empty in the database
    isdoorclosed = models.BooleanField(blank = True, default=False)

"""
class OvenDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #meta describes anything thats not a field
    class Meta:
        model = OvenData
        fields =  ['isdoorclosed']
        exclude = []
        #the labels section is a piece of meta data in the form allowing you to cutomize a field.
        labels = {
            'isdoorclosed': 'Tick here and submit when the door is closed   ',
        
        }
```

[Goal Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxin8.png)

[My pizza oven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rqja.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The reason there are no annotations showing is because you don't have a script tag pointing to the annotations plugin so it's never installed, if you add a script tag pointing at a CDN for the annotations lib as described here they will show: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/integration.html#script-tag

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and your answer. I would like to confirm something: does the CDN need to be provided even if I've installed annotations (I used npm)?

Comment: If you used NPM to install the plugin you will need to import and register it as stated in the documentation also

Comment: I have added the following code in the head section of base.html as per the documentation but unfortunately no result so far. Any further help would be fantastic.

Comment: Then I dont know what could be the problem, you can try to just use the script tag to add it using a CDN as I dont know how NPM and django work together and if that works you will have to look a bit further why django doesnt pick up the package

Comment: ok sure thing, thanks a lot for the input @LeeLenalee!  I'll post back if I find a solution :)